# Why the values of my pivot-table are offset?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I don't understand why the values are swop in the pivot_table in that case. The count doesn't correspond the number of labels I had set with pd.cut().

```
df
    A   B
0  12  75
1  76  34
2  42  62
3  19  15
```

```
df['Cat'] = pd.cut(df2['B'], bins=[0, 25, 50, 75, 100], labels=['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4'])
```

```
df
    A   B Cat
0  12  75  C3
1  76  34  C2
2  42  62  C3
3  19  15  C1
```

```
df.pivot_table(columns='Cat', aggfunc='count')
Cat  C3  C2  C1
A     1   1   2
B     1   1   2
```

I expect the output :

```
Cat  C3  C2  C1
A     2   1   1
B     2   1   1
```

Comment: You should reset your python kernel and try it again. This gives correct output for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In version pandas 0.24.2 it working nice, also is added column with no data `C4`, because categorical:

```
df = df2.pivot_table(columns='Cat', aggfunc='count')
print (df)
Cat  C1  C2  C3  C4
A     1   1   2   0
B     1   1   2   0
```

Alternative solution:

```
df = df2.groupby('Cat').count().T
print (df)
Cat  C1  C2  C3  C4
A     1   1   2   0
B     1   1   2   0
```